# Гугл дает вредные советы?

Tags: html, оптимизация, pagespeed-insights

Читал статьи гугла по оптимизации страниц для ускорения загрузки и наткнулся на интересный пример [здесь](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery#example)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .blue{color:blue;}
    </style>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div class="blue">
      Hello, world!
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="small.css">
```

`<link>` назодится за тегом `<html>`

Что это? Опечатка или так делать нормально?

Comment: Кстати, я на этой странице вижу другой код.

Comment: нормальный код. текст появится мгновенно, чтоб он не моргал цветом добавили отдельный класс сверху. а всякие тенюшки появляются потом

Comment: Почитайте о критическом пути рендеринга веб-страниц, critical css

Comment: Внимательно посмотрите на разметку

Comment: Скорее всего проблема с переводом, если открыть английскую версию, там другой текст и другой пример. Так же стоит обратить внимание, что локализованные версии датированы 2014 годом, а английская 2016. Ну и если посмотреть реальную разметку в браузере - то можно заметить, что тег link был внесен внутрь body

Comment: @NickVolynkin, зависит от выбранного языка

Comment: @eri, а [валидатор](https://validator.w3.org/) считает иначе: `Error: Stray start tag <link>`. Согласно [описанию](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19958777/2553424), это означает запрет на размещение чего-либо за пределами `<body>`.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Is a <link> tag permitted after an </html>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31383791/2881286)

Comment: по каким спецификациям тестировали?

Answer (score 2):

Это не вредный совет. Метатег `link` особенно с объемным css-файлом, размещенный там где он должен быть (в секции `head`) откладывает рендер станицы до полной загрузки css. В коде примера сделаны 2 вещи:

1. В `head` размещен inline-css. Это методика называется critical path css и позволяет отобразить правильно или почти правильно первую 1000 пикселей страницы.
2. Откладывает загрузку полного файла стилей почти до конца рендера страницы.

Второй момент да, не соответствует спецификации, но это легко исправить заменив его простым js-кодом, добавляющим в секцию `head` тег `link` c полным css.

Answer (score 1):

В английской версии этой статьи, видимо более новой, отображается весьма отличающийся пример:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .blue{color:blue;}
    </style>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div class="blue">
      Hello, world!
    </div>
    <noscript id="deferred-styles">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="small.css"/>
    </noscript>
    <script>
      var loadDeferredStyles = function() {
        var addStylesNode = document.getElementById("deferred-styles");
        var replacement = document.createElement("div");
        replacement.innerHTML = addStylesNode.textContent;
        document.body.appendChild(replacement)
        addStylesNode.parentElement.removeChild(addStylesNode);
      };
      var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
          webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
      if (raf) raf(function() { window.setTimeout(loadDeferredStyles, 0); });
      else window.addEventListener('load', loadDeferredStyles);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```